# How can I change the time that an e-mail was received via Microsoft Exchange Server or Microsoft Outlook?

Tags: email, powershell, outlook, exchange-server

As the question says, how can I change the time that an e-mail was received either via Microsoft Outlook or via Microsoft Exchange Server (as an Administrator account) directly?

There are numerous GUI tools online that plug in to Microsoft Outlook and allow you to change various things (including the received date/time) of an e-mail, and these changes are then pushed back to the server.

My question though concerns how to do such without these shareware GUI tools that are available online i.e. directly through Microsoft Outlook or Microsoft Exchange Server (as an Administrator account) using PowerShell or the like.

Comment: The API to use [EWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567668(v=exchg.150).aspx).

Comment: Hi, I wonder why you need to tamper with email dates ?

Comment: MFCMapi - but journaling and audit logs will detect the use of any tool

Comment: I need to change date of the received email on my exchange server. Could you please offer any tools with GUI to edit it  you wrote about?

Comment: @sodawillow Maybe he's implementing Jira Service Management and trying to get the email puller to ingest older emails as tickets.

Comment: @bendodge even though, he should need to modify the message's ReceivedDate; anyway, there's an answer now : )

Answer (score 2):

Outlook Object Model exposes the `MailItem.ReceivedTime` and `MailItem.SentOn` properties. Unfortunately they are read-only, even though your can change these properties using Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) - the properties are `PR_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_TIME` and `PR_CLIENT_SUBMIT_TIME` respectively. Worse than that, OOM has an annoying habit of updating the `ReceivedTime`  property every time `MailItem.Save` is called.

Note that creation and last modification dates cannot be changed using any API - these values are automatically updated by the store provider.

You can manually modify `PR_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_TIME` and `PR_CLIENT_SUBMIT_TIME` properties using [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - select the message, click the IMessage button, double click on these properties to edit them.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (any language, I am its author) is an option, it allows to modify these properties. The following VB script will update the dates of the currently selected message in Outlook:

```
  TheDate = #2015/12/01 2:00 pm#
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
  set Item = Session.GetMessageFromID(Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).EntryID)
  Item.ReceivedTime = TheDate
  Item.SentOn = TheDate
  Item.Save
```